# How to create instance of a class?

Tags: c#

Below is my generic class , I need to access GetAll method for that I need to create instance. How can I create instance if this class to access GetAll method.
Below is my code

```
public class GenericRepository<TContext> : IGenericRepository
            where TContext : DbContext, new()
    {
        private TContext _entities;
        public TContext Context
        {

            get { return _entities; }
            set { _entities = value; }
        }
        public virtual List<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            try
            {
                _entities = new TContext();
                return _entities.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
    public interface IGenericRepository
    {
        List<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    }
```

Comment: Have you ever used C# before? And if not, what are you hoping to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 2):

Because the class is a Generic class it needs to have a type passed to it when creating it like this.

```
IGenericRepository referenceToRepostoryObject = new GenericRepository<MyDbContextClassName>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
var d1 = typeof(GenericRepository<>);
Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(Item) };
var makeme = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
var repository = (IGenericRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(makeme);

repository.GetAll<Item>();
```